# Not able to iterate through QuerySet results with Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm new to Django and I'm experiencing issues with QuerySets.  I am experimenting and trying to get to a field using the Bid.objects.filter method. It's constantly coming up with none if I use any filters (even when I type in an exact match like itemID = "Monkey517").  But if I do an "all" search, it comes up with tons of query sets that I don't know how to iterate through.

I'm using examples I found online and I get the error that "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'itemID'"  or 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'highestBidder'

I'm not sure exactly how to get at each Query set that is inside a larger query set. It's all kind of confusing to me.  Can anyone clear this up for me?

Thanks!

Below is my relevant code:

views.py:

```
   def closeAuction(request):
    username = request.POST.get("username")
    itemID = request.POST.get("itemID")
    query = Bid.objects.all()
    for queries in query.iterator():
        print(query.itemID)
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html")
```

Models.py:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
itemID = models.CharField(max_length=64)
newBid = models.IntegerField()
highestBidder = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

post.html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
       <form name="closeAuction"
             action="/closeAuction"
          method="post" >
            {% csrf_token %}
        <input autofocus class="form-control" type="hidden" name="username" value={{user.username}}>
        <input autofocus class="form-control" type="hidden" name="itemID" value={{p.title}}{{p.price}}>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Close Auction">
    {% endif %}
       </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I see: you are printing the objects `query` instead of `queries`. So you might do:

```
for queries in query:
    print(queries.itemID)
```

instead of

```
for queries in query:
    print(query.itemID)
```

Comment: Thank u that works for a query set that has multiple fields.  How would I print out the data for this query that only selects one field? query = Bid.objects.filter(itemID = itemID).first()   I tried query.itemID but it says query doesn't have that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this code(without `.iterator()`

```
def closeAuction(request):
username = request.POST.get("username")
itemID = request.POST.get("itemID")
query = Bid.objects.all()
for queries in query:
    print(query.itemID)
return render(request, "auctions/index.html")
```

Comment: yes I did.  I tried iterator after doing some searches online.  I get the same results with or without .iterator().  AttributeError at /closeAuction

'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'itemID'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing the query without the for loop? I mean

query = Bid.objects.all()
print(query.filter(itemID=itemID))

Comment: yes and it prints out a QuerySet.  But then how do I get to the data?

Comment: How about "print ([items.ItemID for items in query])"?

Comment: I actually just realized that in the for loop you called query.itemID instead of queries.itemID I guess that may be the problem

Comment: yeah that's the problem with the iteration. It works when I do queries.itemID  But why isn't it working for just one field? I  tried what you did but it's just printing out the brackets [].  I guess it's empty.  But why? when I do the filter it's not getting any data - but when I printed it out like you showed it prints out the data.

Comment: query = Bid.objects.filter(itemID = itemID)
    print(query)
    print([items.itemID for items in query])  Is printing out: None and []  why?  When I use your method above to grab all() and then print out the filter - it works

Comment: Maybe a Bid with a populated itemID field hasn't been created. Or have you created Bid objects whereby the itemID has been specified or filled?

Comment: I figured it out! It's a bit complex to type here but the main question was solved so thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't mind you could post a screenshot of the code or copy and paste ;)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that!